# Unity - How to make circle progress bar using sprite renderer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, progress-bar, sprite

what i have seen so far, people use UI with fill amount, which is not an option for me atm. Does any body know How to make circle progress bar using sprite renderer ?

Comment: Why it's not an option again? If it's still for HP bar or something, you can use UI in world space? Can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution that's not very elegant, but gets the job done.

If you cut your sprite in half (or just use a sprite mask), you can use a sprite mask that rotates to cover up all but what ever percent you want to be shown.

[using rotating a mask to cover parts of a circle.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Lsnj.gif)

Then all you have to do is create a second half sprite that shows the other half.

[Two examples of a finished circular progress bar, one split in half and highlighted to show how it works.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzYhX.gif)

Here's the code I used in the gif above:

```
public class CircularFillBar : MonoBehaviour
{
     public float FillValue;


     private Transform TopHideBar;
     private Transform BottomHideBar;

     void Start()
     {
         TopHideBar    = transform.Find("CircularFillBar (Top)").Find("Rotation Container (moving)");
         BottomHideBar = transform.Find("CircularFillBar (Bottom)").Find("Rotation Container (moving)");
     }

     private void FixedUpdate()
     {
    
         TopHideBar.rotation    = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, (FillValue * 360 > 180 ? 180 : FillValue * 360));
         BottomHideBar.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, (FillValue * 360 < 180 ? 180 : FillValue * 360));




    
         FillValue += 0.002f;

         if (FillValue > 1)
             FillValue = 0;
     }
 }
```

Comment: I wanna say this solution worked perfectly with me. Since I'm a teacher, I have to use this solution whenever working with the creator kit RPG from unity learn. You can't use a world space canvas because of the way they set up the camera and UI. also, if you use this solution and add one more circular mask in the center you can have a hollow circle.

Answer (score 1):

Use Sprite Sheets and Animations instead.
You can find a bunch of them in [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=circular%20sprite%20sheet%20progressbar&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwizvfXpzeLoAhUGI1MKHWVtBmAQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=circular%20sprite%20sheet%20progressbar&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQA1CscViyfGD9fmgAcAB4AIABmQKIAb8SkgEDMi05mAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWc&sclient=img&ei=2uOSXrNohsbMAuXamYAG&bih=754&biw=1604)

Comment: currently proggress bar is UI and im using fillAmount = math.lerp, thus it is smooth, but if i use sprite sheet isnt it became old facion clock? like tik toc. what i mean is,  i need too much sprite to look it smooth, or it will look like some part of circle instantly erasing each second.